# Need to find whether a given key present withing the range of key available and return corresponding index value

Tags: c#, list, search, dictionary

I have large data of iteration count corresponding time started in second. 
Based on any input second need to identify to which particular iteration count that input second belong to using C#.

**Available Data:**

```
string----int
iter_1----00
iter_2----06
iter_3----08
iter_5----20
.
iter_n----n
```

**Desired output**

```
03(input)-iter_1(output),
12(input)-iter_3(output)......
```

input can be as big as 1000 and code need obtain the desired out put based on input sec as many time 1000-10000times.

I am sure this can be possible done using List/Dictionary. I am not sure about Execution Time. Any DataStructure is fine.

Comment: What have you tried already? *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Comment: I won't give you a code, but if I were you I would try using `SortedList` sorted on `int` property, and binary search to find the iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used LIST and used linear search to solve this. Since the data which used to fill the list is sorted. i didn't use sorted list . Didn't find any notable time performance issue on using the list for 1500 item and did a linear search for 30000 time.

```
class Program
{
    //Class to store iteration value and time
    class test
    {
        public String Cycle;
        public int Time;
    };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("test.xml");            
        List<test> Check = new List<test>();

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            // Deatils to fill the list are obtained via XML , which is already sorted.               
            int totsec = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(node.Attributes["ElapsedTime"].Value).TotalSeconds;
            Check.Add(new test() { Cycle = node.Name, Time = totsec });              

        }

        // to Find the iteration , Do linear search via Find Function

        int inputtocheck = 130;

        int index = Check.IndexOf(Check.Find(item => item.Time >= inputtocheck ));
        Console.WriteLine(Check[index].Cycle);

    }
}
```